# WSO2 4.2.0, error while loading online repository

Tags: proxy, repository, wso2

I've just installed WSO2 4.2.0 Carbon, and I need to install additional modules via Feature Management. I tried to add an online repository with no success ("Error occurred while adding repository: http://dist2.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.2.0/").

I don't have the log feature available, but the console shows this:

> org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.core.ProvisioningException: Error occurred while adding repository: http://dist2.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.2.0/
>          at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.core.ProvisioningException.makeExceptionFromErrorCode(ProvisioningException.java:49)

I'm behind a company proxy, but coulnd't find how to set this into WSO2.

I've also tried to add a local repository downloading the repo archive, but after successfully installing a feature (ESB, for example) I cannot install anything else due to missing/wrong dependancies.

How can I set WSO2 to use online repo flawlessly?

EDIT: This is the total output from the console.

```
[2015-01-16 10:38:03,074] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.services.prov.Repos
itoryAdminService} -  Error occurred while adding repository: http://dist.wso2.o
rg/p2/carbon/releases/turing/
org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.core.ProvisioningException: Error occurred while add
ing repository: http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/turing/
        at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.core.ProvisioningException.makeExceptionF
romErrorCode(ProvisioningException.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.core.util.RepositoryUtils.addRepository(R
epositoryUtils.java:88)
        at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.services.prov.RepositoryAdminService.addR
epository(RepositoryAdminService.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.jav
a:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic
(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusines
sLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMe
ssageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessag
e(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessag
e(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.fina
lizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTra
nsportSender.java:77)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisO
peration.java:398)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(Out
InAxisOperation.java:224)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:
149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.stub.RepositoryAdminServiceStub.addReposi
tory(RepositoryAdminServiceStub.java:544)
        at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.ui.RepositoryAdminServiceClient.addReposi
tory(RepositoryAdminServiceClient.java:116)
        at org.apache.jsp.feature_002dmgt.update_005frepository_002dajaxprocesso
r_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.feature_002dmgt.update_005frepository_002dajaxp
rocessor_jsp:118)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
.java:403)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:4
92)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(Con
textPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service
(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(P
roxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyS
ervlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(Delegati
onServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(Charact
erSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(C
ompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(T
omcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValv
e.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.inv
oke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(Ca
rbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoin
t.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unknown Host: http://
dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/turing/content.xml
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCache(C
acheManager.java:189)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRep
ositoryFactory.getLocalFile(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:66)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRep
ositoryFactory.load(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositor
yManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepository
Manager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:749)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepository
Manager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:651)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositor
yManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositor
yManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.core.util.RepositoryUtils.addRepository(R
epositoryUtils.java:77)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: dist.wso2.org
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java
:178)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.events.socket.SocketEventCreate
Util.createSocket(SocketEventCreateUtil.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.ECFHttpClie
ntProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:81)

        at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.ECFHttpClie
ntProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:73)

        at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.ECFHttpClie
ntProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:65)

        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java
:707)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$Http
ConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(Htt
pMethodDirector.java:387)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMe
thodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.jav
a:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.jav
a:346)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientFileSystem
Browser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:232)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowse
r$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
[2015-01-16 10:38:03,106] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.ui.RepositoryAdminS
erviceClient} -  Error occurred while adding repository: http://dist.wso2.org/p2
/carbon/releases/turing/
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error occurred while adding repository: http://dist.
wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/turing/
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.j
ava:531)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(
OutInAxisOperation.java:367)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisO
peration.java:413)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(Out
InAxisOperation.java:224)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:
149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.stub.RepositoryAdminServiceStub.addReposi
tory(RepositoryAdminServiceStub.java:544)
        at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.ui.RepositoryAdminServiceClient.addReposi
tory(RepositoryAdminServiceClient.java:116)
        at org.apache.jsp.feature_002dmgt.update_005frepository_002dajaxprocesso
r_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.feature_002dmgt.update_005frepository_002dajaxp
rocessor_jsp:118)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
.java:403)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:4
92)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(Con
textPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service
(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(P
roxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyS
ervlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(Delegati
onServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(Charact
erSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(C
ompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(T
omcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValv
e.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.inv
oke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(Ca
rbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoin
t.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What is carbon output to stdout and stderr?

Comment: Sorry, just edited with the console output. This time i tried with another repo link (Turing one), but with same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try download the archived p2 (p2repo.zip) repo and use that .

Comment: Quoted from question:

I've also tried to add a local repository downloading the repo archive, but after successfully installing a feature (ESB, for example) I cannot install anything else due to missing/wrong dependancies.